# trouble installing ember model to ember cli app

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-model

I'm running an ember cli app. I'm trying to install ember-model since it suits my api better than ember data; however, I keep running into problems.

The console inspector says that ember-model is installed but gives me the error of it can't find the module ember-model:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: Ember             : 1.11.1
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: jQuery            : 2.1.3
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 0.7.3
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: Ember Model       : 0.0.14
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: -------------------------------
home:24 [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' localhost:35729 0.0.0.0:35729". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-dBUwLbnABTnfa7no4FIMYM3DjtgGo_MdnLBNX10mFLg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

VM1973:81 Ember Inspector Active
loader.js:110Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-model` imported from `task-app/models/address-book/home`
```

as you can see ember model is installed and using version 0.0.14. Why could this error be happening?

Comment: Looking at the commits on github it would appear it's compatible w/ ember 1.11 and 1.12 https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/commit/ac783d4ccabe63574d073f0e0dc265dcb67c95da ... so did you remove ember-data from both the bower.json and package.json files? then also rm -rf if you already installed them locally? This might also be appropriate as a true issue on github for ember-model (assuming this is really broken w/ ember-cli like you are finding)

Comment: @ToranBillups I made sure ember-data is uninstalled removed both folders and their .json files.

Comment: excellent - assumed you did but thought to ask anyway :)

Comment: shameless plug** If ember-model isn't working with ember 1.11 you could give the store + model addon I wrote a try https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-store (it's truly dead simple - the api is 5 methods and includes a simple model that provides dirty tracking w/ rollback support)